# Chile to Sweden without a visa

Tags: visas, visa-free-entry, sweden, chile, chilean-citizens

Okay so I've been to Chile a few times and there have never been a problem, I simply go there, fill a paper out on the plane there, get some kind of small receipt/paper that I can stay for 90 days without any kind of visa when I go through immigration.

I'm just curious if it's the same in the opposite direction? Like a citizen of Chile coming to Sweden without a visa? I've googled and that's what I've come to a conclusion of, but I would like to know for sure. Can my chilean friend just come here as a tourist for 90 days? Will it be the same process? Like just getting a piece of paper saying get out of Sweden within 90 days?

When I come back to Sweden from Chile through Amsterdam, I can just get on another flight to another place in Sweden and walk out of the airport without any kind of immigration. (along with all my other passengers)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You and your friend will go through **immigration checks** at the *first* airport in the Schengen area and through emigration at the *last* airport before leaving. After that, there may be identity checks for security (if you fly) or spot checks at internal borders (by car, train, bike, hiking, etc.), but there will be no stamps at these checks.
- Chile is in 'Annex II' of the Schengen visa policy, so no visa is required. Your friend should be prepared to answer questions about travel plans, and how he is going to pay for them, and how and when he is going to leave again. Then he gets a stamp to record the entry.
- Your friend can stay up to 90 days out of every 180 days. That is, on any day he is in Schengen, count back 180 days and check that he wasn't in Schengen for more than 90 days.

Comment: About the travel plans questions, if I plan on covering most expenses although my friend will bring money as well, but as I said I plan to cover pretty much everything, how do we solve that with whoever is gonna ask them? Plus does it matter if my friend is going as a tourist or going to visit a friend? (me)

Comment: @user99959, there is no difference between visiting a friend or as a tourist. Regarding money, it would be easiest if your friend had access to sufficient money (credit cards, some cash) even if you provide room and board. Of course he should be open if he is asked what he plans to do -- visiting friends is entirely normal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a national of Chile can travel to Sweden (and the rest of the Schengen area) visa-free to visit for a maximum of [90 days out of every 180 days](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13183/3221). Schengen area countries will stamp the passport on entry and exit, rather than issuing a piece of paper at the border.

Reference: [Lists of third countries whose nationals must be in possession of a visa when crossing the external borders and of those whose nationals are exempt from that requirement](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa/docs/visa_lists_en.pdf)

Comment: **Caveat:** Avoid the flights with connections in the USA and Canada, which add the complication of getting an ESTA (basically, an e-Visa) for your transit. This isn't an issue if you transit in the Schengen zone, e.g., go via Madrid.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Why should someone avoid ESTA?

Comment: Risk of refusal. I suppose, since the fee is minimal, you could apply before looking for flights, and if rejected connect in Europe.

Comment: The cheapest flight is likely to be on Iberia with one stop in Madrid anyway, so it probably doesn't matter.